# Schema aware XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt

I am looking for a simple sample for doing schema aware XSLT transformation.
My requirement are as follows:
I have an input.xml that needs to be transformed to output.xml.The output.xml is generated conformant to a schema definition file (schema.xsd).

Xslt should use the schema structures defined in schema.xsd while its generating the output.xml.

Can I please have any specific example

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible. No (efficient) software has been developed to *automatize* the transformation.

So like any other programming, (xslt is a functional programming language) XSLT also needs art and skills :)

At the beginning of usage of XSLT I had browsed seeking such automatized tools:
I had come across one tool called .. "XSLT mapper" [click_here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12483_01/integrate.1013/b28981/xslt_mpr.htm) to follow the link.
I never need it any more.

Please see if it can be useful for you.